# Converting or copying data from CQL3 to CQL2 (Apache Cassandra)

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have collected about 30GiB of data into a CQL3 table, but the current ODBC driver provided by DataStax only supports CQL2. Is there any way to convert my existing data to CQL2 or copy it into a new table?

I would like to use the data in Microsoft reporting tools.

I'm using the latest Cassandra 2 (which uses CQL3 by default it seems) release running on Windows 8.1.

Comment: may be pantago work. m not sure about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datastax Cassandra odbc driver and starting cql2 on cqlsh 3 gives error as cqlsh: error: no such option: -2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201218/datastax-cassandra-odbc-driver-and-starting-cql2-on-cqlsh-3-gives-error-as-cqlsh)

Comment: It's not the same question, I'm asking whether it is possible to migrate data between versions. I only added the ODBC detail as the reason for why I would like to do this. Additionally, that question does not have a workable solution to the problem.